# Angular CLI: sass command not using node-sass but trying to use Ruby sass?

Tags: node.js, angular, sass, angular-cli, node-sass

I have an angular cli project, which packages, runs, and deploys without issue. My problem is, we need to also provide a static CSS file in a separate directory for our CDN deployment (for people using plain html).

So we created an npm script:

`sass --scss --sourcemap=none ./client/src/sass/designsystem/designsystem.scss ./dspackage/dist/css/designsystem.css`

The problem is that when I run it, it is trying to use Ruby Sass.  I get an error:

`/usr/local/bin/sass: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

How can I get it to use node-sass, which is installed correctly both locally and globally?

Before anyone just says to "install ruby sass", I want to compile this css file with the same compiler as the one in our bundle.

This is on OS 10.13.2, angular cli 1.4.4, node-sass@4.7.2

Comment: Isn't the `node-sass` executable named `node-sass` rather than just `sass`?

Comment: yes, indeed.  i also had to change the switches a bit, but that worked

Comment: Can you share the node-sass log? It has a few old incompatible bugs that don't error out properly